# How do I center my inline buttons which using the z-index and an absolute positioning?

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index, responsive

I have set up Slick slider to display a carousel of images for my log in page. I have read that in order to have buttons on front of the carousel I had to utelise `position: absolute` and `z-index: 1` in my CSS. This has allowed me to have my carousel take up the whole of the viewport, but I cannot seem to reposition my buttons or even center them. Usually it would be `text-align: center;` to center buttons but it doesn't seem to be working on this occasion. I am using the jQuery Mobile library.

How can I reposition my buttons so that they always appear in the centre of the viewport, as well as possibly changing the width of the buttons?

[Image Desc. 
**A.** My Login page at the minute. 
**B.** Where I would like my buttons to be, preferably responsive to take up a % of the viewport. 
**C & D.** I can center the buttons in dev tools when I turn off the absolute positioning, but it pushes my slider widget down and does not let the buttons be pushed forward on the z-index.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTczu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhga1.png)

HTML:

```
<body>

<!-- Buttons -->
<div id="LandingButtons">
    <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Sign Up</button>
    <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Log In</button>
</div>

<!-- HTML for images -->
<div class="your-class" ">
      <div> <img src="img/slider/step1.png " alt=" " style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; "></div>
      <div> <img src="img/slider/step2.png " alt=" " style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; "></div>
      <div> <img src="img/slider/step3.png " alt=" " style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; "></div>
      <div> <img src="img/slider/step4.png " alt=" " style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; "></div>
    </div>


<!-- slick.js -->
<script type="text/javascript " src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript " src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript " src="slick/slick.min.js "></script>


<!-- External JS file Initializes the slider  -->
<script type="text/javascript " src
```

CSS:

```
#LandingButtons{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a transform: translateY(-50%);  and a top: 50% combination to get it to the middle of the screen

```
#LandingButtons {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to use margin auto which will help you center align the div: `#LandingButtons{ text-align: center; Margin: 0 auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to center yours element horizontally and vertically you can use this code it should helps you. Also if something is positioned absolute you don’t need to use z-index.

```
.center-div {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

That should be enough and if you use position absolute for that div don’t forget to set position relative for div to which it should be positioned.